# Can I add an invisible bounding box to a three.js scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to detect a click on a bounding box for an object (rather than just on the object itself - more clickable area).  When I load the object like this:

```js
var loader2 = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
          loader2.load( "models/Platform/Platform.json", function(object, materials){
            object.rotation.x = - (Math.PI / 2);
            object.rotation.y = Math.PI;
            object.scale.set(.025, .025, .025);
            object.position.set(0, 1, .4);
            var bbox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(object, 0xffffff);
            bbox.update();
            scene.add(object);
            scene.add(bbox);
            objects.push(bbox);
          });
```

And detect the click like this:

```js
raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        
        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
        document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
        
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        
        function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.clientX = event.touches[0].clientX;
          event.clientY = event.touches[0].clientY;
          onDocumentMouseDown( event );
        }
        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
          console.log("here");
          event.preventDefault();
          mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
          mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
          raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
          console.log(mouse.x);
          console.log(mouse.y);
          var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );
          if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
            console.log("click");
          }
```

The bounding box shows up correctly, and I can click on it!!!!!  However, the bounding box is visible on the screen:

[image]

I want the bounding box to be transparent/invisible/hidden.  Is there any way I can have a bounding box attached to the object which is clickable but not visible?

I read that to make the bounding box invisible I should remove the scene.add(bbox); (not add it to the scene), but if I do that, then it is not in the scene for the ray to intersect, and thus the click is not registered.

Solutions?

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: material.opacity = 0, for example.

Comment: Thanks, @prisoner849!  That helped!  I added bbox.material.opacity = 0;.  Now it's showing less of the lines, but bits and pieces still show up in places.  Don't suppose there's an opacity less than 0? ;)

Comment: also `material.transparent = true;`

Comment: Great thought, @prisoner849!  bbox.material.transparent = true; by itself is actually worse, but if I use both the bounding box is completely transparent!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to set the material to invisible:

```
bbox.material.visible = false;
```

Comment: The `needsUpdate` flag should not be required.

Comment: @WestLangley is correct!  It works without the bbox.material.needsUpdate = true;.

Answer (score 0):

So, there seem to be (at least) two solutions.

As suggested by @prisoner849:

```js
bbox.material.opacity = 0;
bbox.material.transparent = true;
```

As suggested by @tomacco and refined by @WestLangley:

```js
bbox.material.visible = false;
```

Both of these solutions worked for me!

[image]